# Ordering Expanded Entities in OData V4 & WebAPI V2.2

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I'm currently working on building an API using OData V4 via aspnet Web API V2.2.

In summary, I'm calling and expanded property and would like to order the expanded property by date like so:

`http://localhost/odata/Messages?$expand=children($orderby=dateCreated desc)`

The children collection is a parent/child self reference of the same type. The problem isn't the children coming through, its the order that they come through. The PKID for this database uses a GUID so the records don't come through in any specific order. I require the children collection to be ordered by its created date.

According to the OData syntax, this is perfectly fine, but the results are not being ordered properly.

Not knowing how OData works under the hood, my entity framework call looks like the following (using lambda):

`_messageRepo.Get()`

Which simply returns the type `IQueryable<T>` from the underlying database via a `DbSet<>` against EF.

This question has been asked previously on SO and a few other forums but nothing is really conclusive. Also, I've seen a few responses to simply call the data separately which is also an option, but I would like to know if this has been implemented according to OData V4 specification and if so, how can it be implemented.

**UPDATE**
I've also tried using query options like `$top` which also don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Under compliant implementations the syntax is valid to achieve the results you are expecting. So from a general point of view, there is no problem here.

The fact that your implementation is not behaving correctly suggests that either under the hood it is **NOT** using the entity framework directly as the ORM, or `_messageRepo.Get()` is manually applying the query expression (incorrectly), and/or it has not been left to the `EnableQueryAttribute` to process for you.

- This is commonly encountered when repository pattern methods like `_messageRepo.Get()` return `IEnumerable` typed results, instead of `IQueryable`.
- Your function must return an `IQueryable` typed result to enable the OData Query Options to be applied correctly.

> I realise this is an old post but if `$top` also does not work, then this is further evidence that OP's implementation is not a *standard* entity framework implementation, this basic syntax has been supported from the first release of OData v4 in Web API v2.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did create a vanilla EF application to test this before posting with no transformations whatsoever to the same effect. If I have a sub-collection of a different type, no issue, its only when its the same type that it has a problem with child sorting. Nothing you've mentioned above is not implemented/incorrect, it just didn't work at the time.

Comment: Did you solve this in the end though? It's one of those kinds of issues where if I can see all the code then some tweaking here or there might have solved it pretty quick, this kind of query "just works" when nothing gets in the way.